# SQL Subquery performance Improvement required

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have this sub query inside the Update statement. And it is showing a hot spot inside the Execution plan. Please suggest, if some code improvements can be done to gain the performance.

```
--Schema of temp table.
CREATE TABLE #tmpInvestorJob (
    LogID INT,
    [Status] INT,
    JobType VARCHAR(20)
)

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_tmpInv_Status ON #tmpInvestorJob ([Status]);

----#TempTimeline has less than 10 records but has lot of columns.
----#tmpInvestorJob has lots of data inside and is main reason for the slowness.

UPDATE g
SET Completed = ISNULL(a.Completed, 0)
FROM #TempTimeline g
JOIN (
    SELECT LogID,
           COUNT(1) 'Completed'
    FROM #tmpInvestorJob
    WHERE [Status] = 3
    GROUP BY LogID
) a ON a.LogID = g.LogID
```

Please suggest, if we can improve the above Update statement..

Comment: Index `LogID` column as well and see what happens..

Comment: By hotspot do you mean high percentage? You have three statements there, which is the slow onw? assuming it's the `UPDATE`, what does its' query plan look like? any index suggestions or table scans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put an index on LogID in the table #tmpInvestorJob.

This should increase performance since it only count the rows that matches between the tables. It should be much faster because there are only a few rows in #TempTimeline.

```
UPDATE g 
SET 
  Completed =  COALESCE(a.Completed, 0)
FROM #TempTimeline g
-- using outer apply in case no matches are found to set completed to 0
OUTER APPLY 
(
  SELECT COUNT(*) Completed
  FROM #tmpInvestorJob
  WHERE
    [Status] = 3              
    and LogID = g.LogID
) a
```

Comment: I guess you missed the GROUP BY LogID clause inside the query. I will try.

Comment: No I didn't miss it, I removed it on purpose, I joined on LogID so it is not necessary.

Comment: Acc to actual execution plan, the query cost has reduced from 75% to 51% with your suggested changes. I have added clustered index as CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_tmpInv_Status ON #tmpInvestorJob([LogID],[Status]);

Comment: Thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you have Enterprise edition of SQL Server you can create filtered index.

```sql
CREATE INDEX IX_tmpInvestorJob_LogID_Filtered
ON #tmpInvestorJob (LogID) 
WHERE Status = 3
```

If you are on Standard edition and it is very important query I would suggest index with Status. It isn't going be very selective, but this query is going end up using Index Scan anyway. But consider how the index going affect data modification operations.

```sql
CREATE INDEX IX_tmpInv_Status_LogID_Filtered
ON #tmpInvestorJob (Status, LogID)
```

This query is going end up using Index Scan because there are not filters #TempTimeline. Overtime you will have lot of entries with Status = 3 (unless you clean up), so query will become inefficient. You need find a way to apply filter on #TempTimeline table. Completed column contains number of complete jobs, so it can be use for filtering, but you might have another column to limit the recordset.

Another option is to consider an indexed view which would hold an aggregated summary if you have data stored in permanent tables rather than temp tables:

```sql
CREATE VIEW dbo.vwInvCompletedJobStats
WITH SCHEMABINDING
as
SELECT LogID, COUNT(*) Completed
FROM #tmpInvestorJob /* permanent table name*/
WHERE  [Status] = 3 
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_vwInvCompletedJobStats_LogID
ON dbo.vwInvCompletedJobStats (LogID)
GO
```

And use that view for source of the update. Make sure you test effect of Indexed view on other operations.

Comment: I know. I used temp table as place holder. That's why I left a comment /* permanent table name */. And in my comments I mentioned that it will work if he can do this on permanent table. More like longer term idea.

Comment: I missed that part, sorry. Removed comment

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpInvestorJob (
    LogID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Completed INT
)

INSERT INTO #tmpInvestorJob
SELECT LogID, COUNT(1)
FROM ...
WHERE [Status] = 3
GROUP BY LogID

UPDATE g
SET Completed = ISNULL(a.Completed, 0)
FROM #TempTimeline g
LEFT JOIN #tmpInvestorJob a ON a.LogID = g.LogID
OPTION(RECOMPILE)
```